# How bad is Stockfish in Fog of War chess

Tags: engines, chess-variants

Since in Fog of War chess you cant see all the board , I think that engines would suck at it.Have there been any attempts on playing engine tournaments under Fog of War chess?

Comment: [Related resource (off site)](https://github.com/anoojpatel/ImpCatcher)

Comment: *Can* Stockfish play this version of chess?

Comment: Stockfish itself can't, Fairy Stockfish can't either